# Kernel won't connect in Anaconda on my Mac

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, jupyter

Kernel doesn't work and in my terminal I get a syntax error.

I'm using a Mac, I've used Anaconda before. Never had any problems.

File "/Users/aydanaslanova/random.py", line 3
    random_number = random.randint(1,10). 
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

This is the error I am getting. No clue what I'm doing wrong. Did bunch of research still can't fix it.

Kernel should connect. Please help, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: when you say Kernel do you mean a Jupyter Notebook Kernel? how exactly are you running the file?

Comment: Yes. I'm opening Jupyter and starting a new Python file. Silly but when I type import matplotlib.pyplot as plt the colors don't change that's how I also assume there is some issue.

Comment: are you trying to import a file called `random.py`? Can you show me all the code you are trying to run please after you open Jupyter

Comment: I'm not importing random.py that may be the problem too. My code must not be working because kernel won't connect which I'm not sure how to fix? My code is is: import pandas as pd, df = pd.read_csv("happiness.csv"), df

Comment: and when you run that it gives you the `SyntaxError` in the notebook?

Comment: In the notebook it says that it can't connect to kernel, terminal says SyntaxError: invalid syntax.

Comment: Jupyter Notebook
Untitled18
Kernel 
File
Edit
View
Insert
Cell
Kernel
Widgets
Help

​
×
Connection failed
A connection to the notebook server could not be established. The notebook will continue trying to reconnect. Check your network connection or notebook server configuration.

Comment: Can you report that it says when you run this ```jupyter kernelspec list```

Comment: Available kernels:
  python3    /Users/aydanaslanova/opt/anaconda3/share/jupyter/kernels/python3

Comment: ```random.randint(1,10).``` here are you using . at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

renaming `/Users/aydanaslanova/random.py` worked

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aydanaslanova/random.py", line 3
    random_number = random.randint(1,10). 
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: can you type ```jupyter notebook``` to terminal

Comment: ```random.randint(1,10).``` here are you using . at the end?

Comment: Yes, I can type jupyter notebook to terminal. Not putting the . myself, it just shows me that in terminal

Comment: type ```jupyter notebook``` and press enter, does it open a jupyter notebook?

Comment: Yes, it opens it in a new tab

Comment: It seems like the Jupyter installation is fine. Can you type ```x=2``` does it run?

Comment: Just typing x=2 doesn't give me any issues

Comment: Can you type ```import random``` in one cell 
then ```random.randint(1,10)```in another cell

Comment: Do you have a file named random.py in the same folder ?

Comment: Just did. Still connecting to kernel

Comment: You should probably rename this folder ```/Users/aydanaslanova/random.py```

Comment: I was able to fix it! Silly- just needed to change directory. Started a new file in Desktop and it works. Thanks so much!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: Got ya. No worries then.

Comment: Just upvoted your question. You may gain some points. Otherwise, don't worry.